# Compiling openCV for Android and creating a dynamic library

Tags: android, c++, opencv, compilation

I code an Android application that uses openCV to process the camera. I use C++ native code. Everything was working fine until I tried to use cv::motempl, as it is not part of the core but part of the modules.

I downloaded opencv, opencv_contrib, and android-ndk-r16b to compile the modules.
I managed to compile everything for my architecture (armeabi-v7a) but I only get static libs (compiled with -fPic though).

I tried to link all my .a into the libopencv_java3.so I need with the following command line:

```
~/Android/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -shared -o libopencv_java3.so --sysroot=~/Android/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-23/arch-arm/ -L. -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_etc...
```

But the .so file I obtain does not contain the symbols of my static libs (it is like 6140 bytes and Android Studio complains about undefined references).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try compiling your OpenCV libs with "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" as cmake parameter instead. You shouldn't have to manually create your shared library.

Comment: I just stepped on this option reading CMakeCache.txt and came to say it when I read your comment. I still don't have 1 big .so but at least it will work.